# Play and pause media on windows mobile device from a separate app

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, system-calls, windows-media-player

I need to make an app for windows mobile devices which will play and pause media despite of the current player in use. Are there any system calls I can use or any API that I can refer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use background audio player to achive your functionality, here is step by step implementation of your query

[click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):